# Getting an unexpected result on getComputedStyle()

Tags: javascript, userscripts

Any idea why `bodyFontFamily` and `test` are returning "Times New Roman"? My code is running in the browser.

```
let bodyTag = document.querySelector("body");
let bodyTagStyles = window.getComputedStyle(bodyTag);
let bodyFontFamily = bodyTagStyles.fontFamily; // returns "Times New Roman"
let test = bodyTagStyles.getPropertyValue("font-family"); // returns "Times New Roman"
let foo = bodyTagStyles.font; // returns '16px "Times New Roman"'
```

Expanding `bodyTagStyles` shows `fontFamily` = `"Monserrat, sans-serif"`

[image]

The URL of the page is https://demo.directadmin.com:2222/login

The page has a self-signed cert for demo purposes.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/u7r9swdz/

Comment: I assume this piece of code is part of a userscript. It appears that CSS of the page is added dynamically. Therefore, when the userscript runs, the font family hasn't yet been modified and is therefore Times New Roman.